# UITextViewer background image? (ios designer xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, designer

How do i add a background image to TextView in the ios designer?

I thought by making it a sibling but i have no clue how :(.

Picture:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JebJP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a new view and put them in the same view does the trick.